# AWS CLI get credentials/config from root

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

how can I run aws cli command from a user by pointing the profile in root credentials/config file?

I have set the following:

```
export AWS_CONFIG_FILE=/root/.aws/config
export AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE=/root/.aws/credentials
```

my credentials and config file as follow:

```
# /root/.aws/config

[profile xaxa]
aws_access_key_id=xxx
aws_secret_access_key=xxx
region=ap-southeast-2

# /root/.aws/credentials

[profile xaxa]
aws_access_key_id=xxx
aws_secret_access_key=xxx
```

then, i run the following command:

```
sudo aws --profile xaxa ecr get-login-password --debug
```

but its returning me:

> The config profile (xaxa) could not be found

How can i get another user to use root credentials/config file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the full profile name between []. In your case, below should work:

```
sudo aws --profile 'profile xaxa' ecr get-login-password --debug
```

Comment: i tried with that, it still return The config profile (profile xaxa) could not be found

Comment: Can you try  `sudo su` and try again. This time try without sudo in command.

Comment: hmm, this defeat the purpose aye? I want to run aws command from user deploy that uses root credentials/config file in /root/.aws

Comment: AWS creates `.aws/` folder in home directory. As per [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html#cli-configure-files-where) It creates `credentials` file in user's home directory. Hence you need to get into that directory to let it work. Let me know if it worked for you.